# Proof of the Riemann-Lebesgue Theorem in function spaces

Tags: real-analysis

Let $1<p\leq\infty$ and $f\in L^{p}_{loc}(\mathbb{R})$ be a $1$-periodic function. Set $$f_{n}(x)=f(nx)$$ and $$\bar{f}:=\int\limits_{0}^{1}f(x)\, \mathrm{d}x.$$ Then prove that $f_n\rightharpoonup\bar{f}$ in $L^{p}(a,b)$ if $1<p<\infty$ and $f_{n}$ weakly* converges to $\bar{f}$ in $L^{\infty}(a,b)$ if $p=\infty$, as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_0^1f_n(x)g(x)dx=\int_0^n\frac1nf(x)g(x/n)dx=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac1n\int_0^1f(x)g((x+k)/n)dx.$$
Now observe that if $g$ is continuous then
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac1ng((x+k)/n))\to\int_0^1g(x)dx,$$
and apply Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem. Then use that the continuous functions are dense in $L^q(0,1)$ if $q<\infty$ to obtain the assertion in case $(a,b)=(0,1)$ and $1<p<\infty$. The case $(a,b)=(0,N)$ follows by the periodicity of $f$, and from this the general case follows.

How to prove the case $p=\infty$ is not so clear to me since there is no simple presentation of the dual space. Are you sure that not weak$^*$ convergence in $(L^1(a,b))'$ is meant?